# subsetting a vector with column having value equal to zero

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to find out the best model for my data. But, i am getting following error while doing so.

```
list(
  lm(V7 ~ log(V3), hm, subset=(V3>0)), 
  lm(V7~I(1/V3), hm, subset = (V3 >0)),
  lm(V7 ~ log(V3), hm, subset(V3 > 0)),
  nls(V7 ~ I(1/V3*a) + b*V3, hm, subset(V3 > 0), start = list(a = 1, b = 1)), 
  nls(V7 ~ (a + b*log(V3)), hm, subset(V3 > 0), 
    start = setNames(coef(lm(V7 ~ log(V3), hm, subset(V3 > 0))), c("a", "b"))),
  nls(V7 ~ I(exp(1)^(a + b * V3)), hm, subset(V3 > 0), 
    start = list(a=0,b=0)),
  nls(V7 ~ I(1/V3*a)+b, hm, subset(V3 > 0), 
    start = list(a=1,b=1))
)

 Error in subset.default(V3 > 0) : 
 argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: It's `subset=` not `subset()` inside an `lm` or `nls` call. You got it right the first couple of times then changed your mind

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you, it was a silly mistake. I have corrected it but now it is showing error: Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Comment: Please include changes in the question by editing the question. Don't put these changes in the comments.